# How to sort columns values in sql db2-400?

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have 10 columns with similar information, and I would like to sort them asc when greater than 0.
For instance, from this:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | A7 | A8 | A9 | A0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 01 | 00 | 09 | 08 | 05 | 00 | 02 | 06 | 03 |

To this:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | A7 | A8 | A9 | A0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02 | 03 | 05 | 06 | 08 | 09 | 00 | 00 | 00 |

I been trying through `min` and `max` functions to no avail.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Different data should be stored in one column on multiple rows rather than in a single column.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't change the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the data and reaggregate:  One way is:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then a end) as a1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then a end) as a2,
       . . .
from (select a.a,
             row_number() over (order by a desc) as seqnum
      from (select a1 as a from t union all
            select a2 from t union all
            select a3 from t union all
            . . .
           ) a
     ) a;
```

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the seqnum = 1 part, care to explain?

Comment: @FranciscoCosta . . . That does the reordering that you want.

Comment: yes I understand would do that, but not sure what variable "seqnum" should be...

Comment: @FranciscoCosta . . . `seqnum` is defined in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question lol. I used your example as a solution, although after a few tweaks, since I needed to do it by column and by row, it takes much less time than the example from nfgl.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
base (key, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a0) as (
  values
  (1, '00', '01', '00', '09', '08', '05', '00', '02', '06', '03'),
  (2, '08', '02', '00', '06', '01', '02', '00', '04', '03', '09')
),
ordered (k, value, seq) as (
  select
    key,value,rownumber() over(partition by key order by nullif(value,'00')) seq
  from base cross
    join lateral (values a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a0) v(value)
)
select
  key,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 1)) A1,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 2)) A2,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 3)) A3,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 4)) A4,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 5)) A5,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 6)) A6,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 7)) A7,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 8)) A8,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 9)) A9,
  (select value from ordered o where (k, seq) = (key, 10)) A0
from base
```

Comment: Altough your example works exactly as requested, it takes to long to process, I've a huge load of data to process and the reason to use SQL is to make it more efficient, which means run in less time. Thank you though for your example, learned a few things.